# Why does `msiexec /x` fail, while Add/Remove Programs on the Control Panel succeeds?

Tags: windows-10, windows-installer

In Windows 10

```
> msiexec /x "\path\to\myprogram.msi" /quiet
Another version of this product is already installed.  
Installation of this version cannot continue.  
To configure or remove the existing version of this product, use Add/Remove Programs on the Control Panel.
```

I was wondering why `msiexec /x` fails, while Add/Remove Programs on the Control Panel succeeds?

Thanks.

Comment: You are 100% sure your attempting to use the same .msi file to uninstall?  If you were to uninstall the product using Add/Remove then install the program using the command prompt and then attempt to uninstall what happens?

Comment: Yes, I am. The problem happens quite randomly, and the installer msi file is updated constantly.

Comment: What are you using to create this .msi, your problem, is normally a sign that points to the creation of the installer itself.  You should look at the build process of the installer itself, and verify, every single option.

Comment: I build other's C# program, and then uninstall the current program and then install the newly built program.  I am not familiar with their C# program, and they constantly update their program. My question is just asking for possible reasons of one way for uninstalling failing while the other succeeding.

Comment: I will repeat, the problem is the way the .msi is being built, verify its configured to uninstall the previous version before the new version is installed.

Comment: Most of time, tthe current version and the new version are the same, and the author of the program updates the program without changing its version. The uninstallation sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. I am not sure why. Can you elaborate on how to "verify its configured to uninstall the previous version before the new version is installed"?

Comment: Check your build process.  That process would define what your installer does.  Your problem is either with the uninstall portion of your script or the installation portion is checking to see if a previous version is installed and existing instead of doing continuing. *How you solve your build process is out of scope for Superuser.*  Even if it was on topic, you have not supplied the information, to identify the problem with it.

Comment: If you you locate the UninstallString value for the product under either `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\PRODUCTNAMEORGUID` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\PRODUCTNAMEORGUID`, depending on if it's a 64/32-bit installer, what does that have in it?

Comment: @EMK: Thanks. How can I find out the GUID of a program?

Comment: @Tim, well you can usually just do a Find (starting from the \Uninsta‌​ll key) in Regedit and search for the program name/vendor etc.. to find your application.  That said, if you have Orca installed you can open the MSI and under the Property table you can see the ProductCode.

Comment: @EMK: I will do that latter when have a chance (I find that it is not a quick task). Meanwhile, could you explain how the values under the keys are used for solving my problem? Thanks.

Comment: @Tim, the keys and values under the two uninstall keys I mention make up the entries listed in Programs and Features.  The uninstallstring value under the product key is essentially the command called when you uninstall that application from Program and Features.  Application vendors sometimes mark their applications as system components (systemcomponent) to hide them, for example when they have an unified uninstaller but all the details as shown in Programs and Features for that applications comes from the values under the key.